# Eigenvector of unstable and stable manifold of a non-linear system with non-linear center

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

> Show that the system
>
> $\dot{x}=y-y^{3}$
>
> $\dot{y}=-x-y^{2}$
>
> has a non-linear center and plot the phase potrait.

My attempt:

The system is non-linear so we linearise it:

The approximation to the non-linear system is the Jacobian

$J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1-3y^{2}\\ 
-1 &-2y 
\end{bmatrix}$

Note that the fixed points of this system are $\left ( 0,0 \right ),\left ( -1,1 \right ),\left ( -1,-1 \right ).$

$J \mid _{\left ( 0,0 \right )}$ is a neutrally stable center. 
This is a non-linear center as can be checked by time-reversal and spatial reversal symmetry.

$J \mid _{\left ( -1,1 \right )} and \space J \mid_{\left ( -1,-1 \right )}$ are both saddle points.

What is left is determining the direction of the trajectories and the stable and unstable manifold. The stable and unstable manifold is the vector span by the Eigenvector of the associated Eigenvalues.
However, the Jacobian provides a linear approximation to the non-linear system.
Could someone give me a leg up?

Comment: Is the problem written correctly?

Comment: @Moo It has been edited.

Comment: @Moo
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x-y^{2}}{y-y^{3}}$
$\par$
$\frac{dy}{dx}\mid _{\left ( -2,-2 \right )}=-3$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\mid _{\left ( -0.5,-0.5 \right )}=-1.5$

If the first derivative of a function is less than zero on some interval $\mathit{I}$ then the function is decreasing on that interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...*and plot the phase po(r)trait*:

[image]

Comment: Is the second derivative necessary here? If a function is increasing, there are two slopes where it can increase.

Comment: What? Sorry but this is the second completely mysterious comment you are posting... What are you talking about exactly?